# Random timeouts on 1 specific stored procedure from SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure, timeout, azure-sql-database

We have a database hosted in SQL Azure that we connect to through a Cloud Service webapp. Every once a while, one specific stored procedure that returns 100 rows throws a timeout exception when ran from the actual webapp. When we run the same stored procedure with the same parameters from the SQL Management Studio we get the actual results. This issue persists for a while and sometimes disappears as fast as it occurred.

Other stored procedures and data retrieval from our application works like a charm, but one specific SP has this issue, which is weird. When the issue occurs, we can temporarily fix it by adding something like `WHERE 1=1` into the where clause. Then it works for a while, but at some point the whole things starts all over again. I cannot get a grip on what's going wrong here or what could be causing this. We also added `WITH RECOMPILE` to the stored proc, but to no avail.

Comment: SQL Azure Standard or Premium database ? How long does the stored procedure take to run i.e Are you close to the limit ? Have a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394114.aspx and specifically Monitoring Query Performance. Just check you don't have a performance bottleneck in it.

Comment: It's a SQL Azure Web edition database of 1GB. Usually the stored procedure takes about 2 seconds, but as soon as this issue hits it goes on for 30 seconds and just times out (default SqlCommand timeout). However when I adjust it with something nonsensical it immediately goes back to running in 2 seconds again. This issue only occurs on the production environment in Azure and not locally or on a "normal" server. To me that sounds a bit like something is being cached and invalidated as soon as the procedure is altered, but I wouldn't really know where to look.

Comment: Did you find the query on the bottleneck list ?

Comment: I checked and it's at the top of the list. However, I wouldn't know how to rewrite it differently.

Comment: In Sql Server Management Studio run a Display Estimated Execution Plan and you should be able to see the cost of query but also if there is potential to add an index or two which will speed up the performance.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing with mine.  I checked the execution plan and everything looked fine.  So I copied the database to my local machine and it ran there without any problems.  Finally I decided to drop and recreate the stored procedure that was timing out.  After doing that, the SP ran normally again with no timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue especially after upgrading or downgrading a server. We found that a quick alter including "with recompile" fixes the problem. We turn recompile off after we've altered it once. Not sure if Azure gets some kind of corruption in the execution plan or what is happening. Not convinced you need "with recompile" you may just need to do the alter.